# Restoring docker moved images

Tags: ubuntu, docker

My hard disk was full so I moved the docker images to a new location temporarily. After some while I copied them back to their primary location on my hard disk. However when I want to run the images:
`sudo nvidia-docker run -i -t 3016077714e2 /bin/bash`
I get the following error:

`docker: Error response from daemon: open /media/newhard/aufs/layers/968339bf09d1e96daa2c101fb4f811a473ee28dccc90e5e14fe4c5012afd5ff6: no such file or directory.
See 'docker run --help'.`

I have no idea of what has happened and How I can restore the images.

Comment: What process did you follow to move the data?

Comment: I just moved the data to my new hard disk using `mv` command.

Answer (score 0):

*aufs* is Docker's file storage which handles the layers of images and writable layers of containers. Trying to manipulate this can cause malfunctions in your Docker image and containers structure. You must move them back the same way you move them out.

If ever, you really can't retrieve the previous state then you can just change your filestorage to overlay2 which has better performance than aufs. Worst case scenario is you need to start your docker from scratch with `rm -rf /var/lib/docker/*`